# Question about expectation of distribution of maximum of i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Assume $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables sampled from a continuous distribution, $F(X_1,X_2,...X_n) = k$, if $X_1 < X_2 <...< X_{k - 1} > X_k$. What is the expectation of $F$?

I'm not sure where to start here. Is this essentially asking for the expectation of the distribution of the maximum of i.i.d. random variables? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think we have $$F=2+\mathbf1_{\{X_1<X_2\}}+\mathbf1_{\{X_1<X_2<X_3\}}+\cdots+\mathbf1_{\{X_1<X_2<\cdots<X_n\}}.$$
Thus $$\mathbb E\,F=2+\mathbb P(X_1<X_2)+\mathbb P(X_1<X_2<X_3)+\cdots+\mathbb P(X_1<X_2<\cdots<X_n).$$
Now $\mathbb P(X_1<X_2<\cdots<X_k)=\frac1{k!}$ (why?)

Comment: Thank you @nejimban! How did you get that $F=2+\mathbf1_{\{X_1<X_2\}}+\mathbf1_{\{X_1<X_2<X_3\}}+\cdots+\mathbf1_{\{X_1<X_2<\cdots<X_n\}}$ (specifically where did the 2 come from)? As for $\mathbb P(X_1<X_2<\cdots<X_k)=\frac1{k!}$, is it because the variables are all i.i.d. no one variable is more likely to be greater than any other. So there are $k!$ orderings of the random variables, and this order $X_1<X_2<\cdots<X_k$ has probability $\frac{1}{k!}$.

Comment: I put $2$ there because it seemed to me from the definition of $F$ that $F=1$ was not possible. (But you should check the definition for $k=1$ or $k=n$.) Note also that you should also justify why events like $X_1<X_2=X_3<X_4$ have probability $0$ to occur.